# NHibernate - set reference to null on delete

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the fallowing NHibernate-Mapping:

```xml
<class name="Activity" table="Activity" lazy="false"  >
<cache usage="read-write"/>
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid">      
                <generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
<property name="Subject" column="Subject" type="String" length="255"  />
<many-to-one  name="ParentActivity" class="Activity" foreign-key="FK_Activity_ParentActivity" lazy="proxy" fetch="select">
    <column name="ParentActivityId"/>
</many-to-one>
<set name="Activities" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="none" >
    <key>
        <column name="ParentActivityId"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="Activity"/>
</set>
```

I have now an Entity Activity (x) which has another Entity Activity (y) set as ParentActivity.
I am searching for the solution, that, when I delete the entity y, the reference from x to y is set to null. Now I become an error, that I cannot delete x because of the FK_Activity_ParentActivity.
Can someone point me to the right way how I can do this? - Thanks.

Comment: How do you want it to behave when y is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this post of Ayende Rahien will help you: [the different between all all-delete-orphans and save-update](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update)

> Here is what each cascade option means:
>
> - none - do not do any cascades, let the users handles them by themselves.
> - save-update - when the object is saved/updated, check the associations and save/update any object that require it (including
>     save/update the associations in many-to-many scenario).
> - delete - when the object is deleted, delete all the objects in the association.
> - delete-orphan - when the object is deleted, delete all the objects in the association. In addition to that, when an object is removed
>     from the association and not associated with another object
>     (orphaned), also delete it.
> - all - when an object is save/update/delete, check the associations and save/update/delete all the objects found.
> - all-delete-orphan - when an object is save/update/delete, check the associations and save/update/delete all the objects found. In
>     additional to that, when an object is removed from the association and
>     not associated with another object (orphaned), also delete it.